# Windows Forms - Single Instance - Include Statement

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

When I try to use #include "CFIS_Main.h" statement in form "For_Student_Details.h", 
Its not accepting...Anybody can point me the mistake? Thanks for the helps..

```
MyProject.cpp
// MyProject.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#ifndef CFIS_Main_h
#define CFIS_Main_h
#include "CFIS_Main.h"
#endif

using namespace MyProject;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew CFIS_Main());
    return 0;
}
```

## My Codes from MdiParent

```
//CFIS_Main.h  IsMdiContainer = True

#include "For_Student_Detials"


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
For_Student_Detials^ MyStudentDet= For_Student_Detials::GetForm(true,this);
MyStudentDet->MdiParent=this;
MyStudentDet->FormBorderStyle=System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::None;
MyStudentDet->Dock=DockStyle::Fill;
MyStudentDet->Show();
}
```

## My Codes From MdiChild For_Student_Details

```
#include "CFIS_Main.h"  Why Not included...?????

public: static For_Student_Details^ For_Student_Details::_instance = nullptr;
public: static For_Student_Details^ For_Student_Details::GetForm(bool^ IsMDIChild, CFIS_Main^ MyInstFrm) {
if (_instance == nullptr)
    _instance = gcnew For_Student_Details();

if (_instance->IsDisposed)
    _instance = gcnew For_Student_Details();

if (IsMDIChild)
    _instance->MdiParent = MyInstFrm;

return _instance;
}
```

Receiving The Below errors

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CFIS_Main'
error C2065: 'MyInstFrm' : undeclared identifier
error C2660: 'CashFlow_InformationsSystem::For_Loan_Details::GetForm' : function does not take 2 arguments
```

From the above code, Its not including CFIS_Main, I can't identify my mistake, Does anybody can point me? 
Thanks For The Helps

Comment: None of these include files define a `CFIS_Main` type.  It looks like you are forgetting to include something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular header reference:

- "For_Student_Details" includes "CFIS_Main.h"
- "CFIS_Main.h" includes "For_Student_Details"

You will need to resolve this circular dependency.

The easiest way to do so is to leave only the function *declaration* for `button1_Click()` in "CFIS_Main.h" and move the *definition* into "MyProject.cpp", where you also include "For_Student_Details".

You will also have to define (or include the right header) the type `CFIS_Main` referenced in `For_Student_Details::GetForm()` (this might be resolved once you fix the circular include problem)

Also, place the include guards in your header files, not the .cpp files